# Calendar does not show app in the privacy settings

Tags: iphone, calendar

In my app I have added a button to add reminder to `iPhone calendar`. I have used `EKEventEditViewController.` It is presented to user and user `add to calender`. It is working on my iPhone and also I find app listed in `calender privacy setting`. But client cannot find app listed in `iPhone calender privacy settings. Is there any setting in plist that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the app is targeted for iOS 6

Remember the app must "ask" the user if the app can access the calendar.

```
[eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showCalendarEventViewControllerWithEventStore:) withObject:eventStore waitUntilDone:YES];
    }] ;

-(void) showCalendarEventViewControllerWithEventStore: (EKEventStore *) eventStore
{
    EKEventEditViewController * vc = [[EKEventEditViewController alloc] init];

    EKEvent* event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Take %@" , self.prescription.lastFilledLabelName];
    event.startDate = [[NSDate date] dateByRoundingToNextMinute:15];
    event.endDate = [event.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:15*60];
    event.notes = self.prescription.directions;
    EKAlarm *alarm = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-15*60] ;
    event.alarms = [NSArray arrayWithObject:alarm];

    vc.eventStore = eventStore;
    vc.event = event;

    vc.editViewDelegate = self;
    vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

After the user runs the app once, then the app will show up in the privacy settings.